# Distance from settlements to major roads: Network analyst, OD Cost Matrix

Tags: arcgis-desktop, distance, network-analyst, integration

I am trying to identify the closest driving/walking distance to major roads. I have settlements (points), the road from OSM (polylines), and major roads (polylines).

I have tried Network Analyst but it only works for few settlements because most of the settlement points are not located right on the OSM roads. I have tried Integration tool (Data Management) to put them on the roads but it messes up the settlements data.

What would be the easiest way to find the shortest driving/walking distance from settlement points to closest point of major roads' polylines?

I am using ArcGIS Desktop 10.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should increase the "search tolerance" in network analysis settings ([screenshot](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/guide-books/extensions/network-analyst/snapping-network-locations-with-build-query.htm)). This value defines the maximum "snapping distance", in which points are snapped to your road network.